# Почему результат после .split() сдвинут на одну позицию?

Tags: python, dataframe

У меня есть датафрейм с колонкой `df['address']` в которой содержится адрес примерно вот такого формата: `12951 Williams Crossing\nJohnnyville, DC 30723`

Мне нужно создать отдельную колонку `df['zip_code']` в которой будет содержаться только индекс (последние 5 цифр адреса - в случае примера выше - `30723`).

```
# Making a list
list1 = []

for i in df['address']:
    a = str(i).split()[-1]
    list1.append(a)

# Making a dataframe out of list1:
zuk = pd.DataFrame({'zip_code':list1})

# Concatenating a new dataframe with the old one
df = pd.concat([df,zuk], axis=1, sort=True)
```

В результате, `len(df)` получается 396030 rows вместо 396029 исходных.

Откуда берется дополнительный ряд? При беглом анализе `df`, колонки `'address'` и `'zip_code'` соответсвуют друг другу.

Comment: Проходить циклом по датафрейму - одно из самых НЕУДАЧНЫХ решений. Что говорит у вас df.info() после всех преобразований?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зачем вы используете pandas, если полностью игнорируете ее векторизованные функции? какой смысл тогда?

Вместо всего вашего кода в вопросе, попробуйте выделить зип-код в отдельную колонку так:

```
df["zip"] = df["address"].str.split().str[-1]
```